# FK conflict on a table that the data definitely exists in

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
UPDATE MysterySpells SET SpellId = (SELECT Id FROM Spells
    WHERE Name = 'unseen servant')
WHERE MysteryId = 1 And ClassLevel = 2
```

I know the subquery returns `589`.  Anyone have any clues why I would be getting this error:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_MysterySpells_Spells". The conflict occurred in database "x",
>   table "dbo.Spells", column 'Id'.

**CODE UPDATE**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Spells](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OldId] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [School] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SubSchool] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SchoolID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SubSchoolID] [int] NULL,
    [CastingTime] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Components] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [IsCostly] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Cost] [int] NULL,
    [RangeDescription] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Range] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RangeIncrement] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RangeGap] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Area] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AreaIncrement] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AreaGap] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AreaNote] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ShortDescription] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Targets] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Effect] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Duration] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [SavingThrow] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [SpellResistence] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [HasVerbal] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [HasSomatic] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [HasMaterial] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [HasFocus] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [HasDivineFocus] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [WizardLevel] [int] NULL,
    [ClericLevel] [int] NULL,
    [AdeptLevel] [int] NULL,
    [AlchemistLevel] [int] NULL,
    [AntipaladinLevel] [int] NULL,
    [BardLevel] [int] NULL,
    [BloodragerLevel] [int] NULL,
    [DruidLevel] [int] NULL,
    [InquisitorLevel] [int] NULL,
    [MagusLevel] [int] NULL,
    [OracleLevel] [int] NULL,
    [PaladinLevel] [int] NULL,
    [RangerLevel] [int] NULL,
    [ShamanLevel] [int] NULL,
    [SorcererLevel] [int] NULL,
    [SummonerLevel] [int] NULL,
    [WitchLevel] [int] NULL,
    [SLALevel] [int] NULL,
    [IsDismissible] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsLanguageDependent] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsShapeable] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsAcid] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsAir] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsCold] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsCurse] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsDarkness] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsDeath] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsDisease] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsEarth] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsElectricity] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsEmotion] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsFear] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsFire] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsForce] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsLight] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsPain] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsPoison] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsShadow] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsSonic] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsWater] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsChaotic] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsEvil] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsGood] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsLawful] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsMindAffecting] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsMythic] [bit] NULL,
    [MythicDescription] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Augmented] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Spells] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]




CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MysterySpells](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MysteryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ClassLevel] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SpellId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SpellLevel] [int] NULL,
    [Restrictions] [varchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MysterySpells] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MysterySpells]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MysterySpells_Mysteries] FOREIGN KEY([MysteryId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Mysteries] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MysterySpells] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MysterySpells_Mysteries]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MysterySpells]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MysterySpells_Spells] FOREIGN KEY([SpellId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Spells] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MysterySpells] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MysterySpells_Spells]
GO
```

Comment: Maybe because your sub query returns NULL?

Comment: Maybe I said in my original post that the SubQuery returns 589? I tested it before I said it so that I wouldn't be lying.

Comment: Check foreign key, if it looks on  Spells table. Check for triggers. What happens if you write `UPDATE MysterySpells SET SpellId = 589
WHERE MysteryId = 1 And ClassLevel = 2`?

Comment: I wrote everything; I know there are no triggers.  The value 589 exists.  I get the value 589 from the Spells table, yet it tells me there is an FK conflict on the Spells table when I try to update the SpellId field in MysterySpells.
And the same error happens. (I had tried that as well, just in case the variables I am using weren't working).  Technically 'unseen servant' and the MysteryId are variables.

Comment: @RobertBurke, what about last question? Can you provide us with cerate table scripts of both?

Comment: Added the Create scripts

Comment: So based on the scripts you added to the question, there is absolutely no FK on the Spells table.   And yet you're getting a FK error on the table Spells.   The only possible answer then, is that you have a defective version of SQL Server.

Comment: @TabAlleman Is it saying there is?  I thought it was saying  thatthere is an FK conflict on the constraint that is called 'FK_MysterySpells_Spells' which is defined on MysterySpells and that the place that is causing it is Spells since that is where the source data comes from.

Comment: I'm wondering if I might not just need to recreate the Spells table then.

Comment: Since this can return 0 or more rows it is not good syntax SpellId = (SELECT Id FROM Spells
    WHERE Name = 'unseen servant')

Comment: @Blam Considering I am 99.99999% sure there is only one instance of each string in the table, I will only get one result.  This is also not some sort of production code, I am just repairing some references to these IDs that I screwed up; so it doesn't matter if I get more than one result, I can handle that.  Also, your comment doesn't help my problem.

Comment: I am 99.99999% that is not a good practice even for repair.  Why not clean up your code?

Comment: Still not relevant to my question. Since I am running this code by hand, I don't run the update code unless I know the sub query is not returning null or multiple results by testing each result first. Please stay on topic.

Comment: Clean code is relevant.  Why practice sloppy code?  Why post sloppy code?  Sloppy question don't get attention.  Questions that refute or ignore feedback don't get attention.  Questions that won't test suggestions don't get attention.

Comment: So since you are so adamant about going off topic, how do you propose I update the records I erased on accident?  How is it sloppy if I validate the data exists?  I have to do this by hand because I erased the ID references on accident and the only way to find them again is go to my source, find the name of the spell, type it in, get the ID and insert it into the valid record.  Am I supposed to find the ID and type it in by hand? You are the only person I am ignoring because you are being pretentious and off topic.

What suggestions have I not tested?  No one has given me a solution to test.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, here is how I debug

If you expect

```
SELECT Id FROM Spells WHERE Name = 'unseen servant'
```

to return 589
I will hard code it to 1 first.

```
UPDATE MysterySpells SET SpellId = 589
WHERE MysteryId = 1 And ClassLevel = 2
```

If the error still there, I will check if table Spells contains value where Id = 589 and Name = 'unseen servant'.

I believe you will find the root cause somewhere in the process.

Note: It would be better if you show us the table structure and data inside.

Comment: The 589 comes from the same table that the FK conflict is being referenced to.  How can it not exist?
I've already confirmed that running the subquery returns 589...that's how I know it returns 589.

Comment: @RobertBurke What is the problem with testing answer?

Comment: @RovertBurke have you tried this yet?

`UPDATE MysterySpells SET SpellId = 589
WHERE MysteryId = 1 And ClassLevel = 2`

Comment: @Rawitas Did you not even read the other posts? This was already discussed above.

Comment: @RovertBurke I can't find any result from GiorgiNakeuri 's or my query. I know you got 589 from 
(SELECT Id FROM Spells WHERE Name = 'unseen servant'). I only ask you to skip that query and hard code 589 in your update statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that it does not know what value to grab. There is no mapping defined between spells and mystery spells in your query. The current update is actually trying to update each row in MysterySpells with 589 records.

If you simply wanted to map all of your mystery spells to a single spell you can do:

```
UPDATE MysterySpells SET SpellId = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Spells
WHERE Name = 'unseen servant')
WHERE MysteryId = 1 And ClassLevel = 2
```

If there is a pre-existing mapping between these 2 tables and you are expecting to update MysterySpells based on a relationship with spells table:

```
UPDATE MysterySpells
SET SpellID = t2.ID
FROM MysterySpells t1
JOIN Spells t2 ON t2.relation = t1.relation
```

If there isn't any existing mapping and you are trying to do this to create this as the mapping you have few options.

1) If no other relationship exists map by hand

2) If their is a relationship that can be calculated, but is not available through an existing join, you can take advantage of the row and partition functions to relate the two. Then use an update similar to the 2nd code block I posted.

Comment: Just realized 589 was the key you said you saw, not the count of records. So my answer may not be relevant.